# Continue after a certain command in terminal finish

Tags: c#, cmd, process, terminal

i needed to ask a question which i really couldn't find on the internet.. i'm using Process to open cmd in my c# application.. i need to pass some commands but after each command i need to make sure this command finished so i could continue the other!.. how's that possible with the system.diagnostics... here's my code that i tried..

```
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
      {
          FileName = "cmd.exe",
          RedirectStandardInput = true,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          CreateNoWindow = false,
          WorkingDirectory = @"E:/Visual Studio 2013/" + project_Name + "/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.4.1/tools"
      };

      var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

      process.Start();
      process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nunit3-console.exe E:/Debug/Report_Testing.dll");


      process.WaitForExit();
```

wait for exit here hangs infinitely and i can't get to pass this line of code.
what's the solution for this !?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option `/c nunit3-console.exe E:/Debug/Report_Testing.dll`.

As it is now, it will run `cmd` and the prompt will remain alive after the command. `WaitForExit` is waiting for `cmd` to finish and it never will.

Comment: i can't understand you Uno i'm sorry, i want to know when the command finishes ... what does the option /k do ? also you want me to add it in the writeline line ??

Comment: @OmarEl-elamy your process starts `cmq`, not the nunit runner, so it is attached to that one for the termination. If you want to close it in your code you should send `exit` to the command line, but I don't think that would be really elegant.

Comment: The test runner is running as a **child** of cmd, so even if the runner exits, the parent doesn't.

Comment: /c is not recognized as internal or external command ? is there something i have to download ?

Comment: so what could i do to even close the terminal after the runner exits ? i.e. after the command finishes .. this could be an option also ??

Comment: sending exit is an option but does it wait for the runner to finish ?!

Comment: You get the error because you added the option to the filename property I guess. There is another property on `Process` for options.

Comment: I believe it will, it will behave the same way as if you typed "exit" on a "on screen" command prompt during the other command.

Comment: how would this /c help ??

Comment: no Uno, i tried exit after the standardinput directly i found out that the runner is working normally while the code already passed the exit command, although the cmd gets closed in the task manager.. i think this is because the cmd already executed the command and doesn't need anymore to wait for it to finish.. i don't know actually

Comment: @OmarEl-elamy I'm not even sure why you are running cmd, why can't you just invoke nunit-runner in the process?

Comment: and how would that be ??

Comment: Set the runner as filename for the process. But this is not the C# customer service so if you have other questions search or ask on the site, not here.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to get to the solution:

I've added this to my writeline command and changed it to be like this:

```
      process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nunit3-console.exe E:/Debug/Report_Testing.dll" + "&" +"exit");
```

//Then use wait for exit
process.WaitForExit();

by this i made sure that the command is executed.

Comment: That is really nasty, I would try to execute the one time command.

Comment: one time command how ?? i just want to finish it then exit ??